# How to pass alias through sudo

Tags: shell, sudo, alias

I have an alias that passes in some parameters to a tool that I use often.  Sometimes I run as myself, sometimes under sudo.  Unfortunately, of course, sudo doesn't recognise the alias.

Does anyone have a hint on how to pass the alias through?

In this case, I have a bunch of options for perl when I'm debugging:

```
alias pd='perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
```

Sometimes, I have to debug my tools as root, so, instead of running:

```
pd ./mytool --some params
```

I need to run it under sudo.  I've tried many ways:

```
sudo eval $(alias pd)\; pd ./mytool --some params
sudo $(alias pd)\; pd ./mytool --some params
sudo bash -c "$(alias pd)\; pd ./mytool --some params"
sudo bash -c "$(alias pd); pd ./mytool --some params"
sudo bash -c eval\ "$(alias pd)\; pd ./mytool --some params"
sudo bash -c eval\ "'$(alias pd)\; pd ./mytool --some params'"
```

I was hoping for a nice, concise way to ensure that my current pd alias was fully used (in case I need to tweak it later), though some of my attempts weren't concise at all.  My last resort is to put it into a shell script and put that somewhere that sudo will be able to find.  But aliases are soooo handy sometimes, so it is a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish I could mark two answers as "correct".  Combining the Right Way from [Insyte](https://serverfault.com/users/10380/insyte)'s, um, insightful post, with the awk (or cut) solution from [Bill Weiss](https://serverfault.com/users/4117/bill-weiss), I've come up with this:

```
alias spd="sudo $(alias pd | cut -d\' -f2)"
```

Now I'll just go and put this into a shell function in my .bashrc or something, and then create "s" versions of all my aliases that I desire to run as root.

**Update**: slight modification of [Dennis Williamson](https://serverfault.com/users/1293/dennis-williamson)'s simplistic function to make it a bit easier to use:

```
 salias()
 {
   local a c
   a=$(echo "$1" | cut -f1 -d=)
   c=$(echo "$1" | cut -f2- -d=)
   alias $a="$c"
   alias s$a="sudo $c"
 }
```

This means I just have to put "s" in front of the entire command.  Instead of:

```
alias pd='perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
```

I just add the s in the front.

```
salias pd='perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
```

And I'm done.  Sure, the computer does a bit more work, but that's what a computer is for.  :-)

Thanks!

Comment: You can (or should be able to) mark things as accepted, which is kind of like marking them correct :)

Comment: Right - I want to mark *two* answers as correct :-P

Comment: Why not Slizzered's answer? `alias sudo="sudo "` works perfect.

Answer (score 55):

A *very* elegant solution can be found in the Archlinux-Wiki:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
# whitespace ---^
```

works to pass all aliases to `sudo`.

Source: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Passing_aliases

Comment: This is a great trick! For the curious, the explanation from the alias section in the bash manpage: `A trailing space in  value causes the next word to be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded.`

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: It is a shame that this does not work for functions.

Comment: __Note:__ Supposing you DO need to pass an __option__ to `sudo` again, while wanting to keep that `sudo`-passthrough trick at the same time. Even this can be done: to use options again, use `\sudo`. The backslash will *override* the alias. (Many don't seem to know about that). This way, you can (*danger!*) even remove files without *any* warning, overriding the `alias rm='rm -i'` commonly specified in `.bash-aliases`, simply by typing `\rm file-to-delete`.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not real clear on what you're trying to do.  I can see two ways:

### The Right Way

`alias pd='sudo perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'`

Then executing `pd ./mytool` will execute your debugging command as root but still preserve the benefits of sudo (audit trail, not operating out of a root shell).

Example:

```
insyte$ alias sid='sudo id'
insyte$ sid
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

### The Easy Way

Add the aliases to root's `.bashrc` and use `sudo -i` whenever you sudo to root.

```
root# echo 'alias fb="echo foo bar"' >> /root/.bashrc
root# exit
exit
insyte$ sudo -i
root# fb
foo bar
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what all the debate is about. Insyte's "Right Way" seems easiest, and in a departure from the norm, also seems most intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

from http://www.shellperson.net/using-sudo-with-an-alias/

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Answer (score 4):

**Just have two aliases and use a variable**

I don't see the reason for using `awk` or `cut` unless it's to only have the core alias defined once in order to make it easier to modify. If that's the case, then this works:

```
# ... in .bashrc ...
pd='perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
alias pd="$pd"
alias spd="sudo $pd"
```

Here's a simplistic function to make alias pairs such as the one above:

```
mkap () {
    alias $1=$2
    alias s$1="sudo $2"
}
```

To use:

```
mkap pd 'perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
mkap ct 'cat'
```

Now you have `pd` and `spd` plus `ct` and `sct`.

```
$ ct /etc/shadow
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
$ sct /etc/shadow
[sudo] password for dennis:
root:[censored]...
$ alias
alias ct='cat'
alias pd='perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
alias sct='sudo cat'
alias spd='sudo perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply hack out a script that includes your options, then place it somewhere in one of the folders that is the path for regular account and root?  It really wouldn't take much of a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d $*
```

Comment: It actually has to be "$@" instead of $*, and that's part of the reason I generally try to avoid it.  ;-)  It works, it just wastes a bunch of disk space relative to what it contains.

Answer (score 3):

This is rough, but it works here:

```
houdini@clanspum:~/ > alias fb
fb='echo foo bar'
houdini@clanspum:~/ > alias fb | awk -F\' '{print $2}'
echo foo bar
houdini@clanspum:~/ > sudo sh -c "$(alias fb | awk -F\' '{print $2}')"
foo bar
houdini@clanspum:~/ > sudo sh -c "$(alias fb | awk -F\' '{print $2}') a b c"
foo bar a b c
houdini@clanspum:~/ > fb
foo bar
houdini@clanspum:~/ > fb a b c
foo bar a b c
```

Comment: I pasted an incomplete solution here, then edited to fix.  The current one is right.

A free upvote to the first person to comment explaining what's going on here :)

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler way than awk, but hope != reality sometimes ;-)  Apparently, "cut -f2 -d\'" would work just as well as awk, and be that tiny bit shorter.

Comment: Yeah, cut would work, I always forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

**Add a "sudo " prefix** to selected **aliases AND commands** from within your `~/.bashrc` like so:

```
#a regular alias
alias pd='perl -Ilib -I/home/myuser/lib -d'

#sudofy (command id, alias pd - add others to this list)
for cmd in id pd;
      do alias "s$cmd"="sudo $cmd";
done;
```

Comment: That doesn't work - that's where I started from.  Did you try it?

Comment: Nice concept. I think `alias sudo="sudo "` is easier though.

Answer (score 3):

As posted a few times, do in '.bashrc':

alias sudo='sudo '

The reason why is explained in 'man bash' and 'help alias':

alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
    Define or display aliases.

```
Without arguments, `alias' prints the list of aliases in the reusable
form `alias NAME=VALUE' on standard output.

Otherwise, an alias is defined for each NAME whose VALUE is given.
**A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
alias substitution when the alias is expanded.**
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
(alias; echo "exec < /dev/tty") | sudo bash  -i
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but ISTR that `bash -i` (i = interactive) is v4.0 only. So on an older server that still got `bash` v3 running, this would most likely fail. But prove me wrong, anyone, go ahead ;)

Comment: @syntaxerror - You remember wrong. `-i` is Bourne shell, see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html

Comment: Wow, didn't expect to get a reply so soon for a 6+-year-old post...Why yes, I might have confused it with `#!/bin/bash -i` after the shebang, which is apparently not the same (?). To cut a long story short, using `history` in a `bash` script (and not on the "live" command line) *will* require the `-i` option, which I was unable to get working on a server with "only" `bash` v3 installed. And that's a fact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the wisest thing to do on a production box but locally I use

```
alias sudo="sudo -E"
```

> > The -E (*preserve environment*) option will override the env_reset option in sudoers(5)).  It is only available when either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in sudoers(5).

Answer (score -1):

Can you add the alias to root's .bashrc or just execute .bashrc through sudo before your command?

```
sudo (. ~yourlogin/.bashrc; pd ./mytool --some params)
```

Comment: Um, this didn't even almost work, either.  It's actually fairly close to some of the things I tried above, but is further away from actual shell/sudo syntax.